# How do I encode Feign HTTP GET request params using Jackson?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, feign

I'm quite new to Feign. My aim is to use the Jackson Encoder/Decoders via HTTP to communicate between clients. To achieve this I used the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
protected static class JacksonFeignConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public Decoder feignDecoder() {
    return new JacksonDecoder();
  }
  @Bean
  public Encoder feignEncoder() {
    return new JacksonEncoder();
  }
```

}

While this appears to format the body of requests, it does not format request parameters (using @RequestParam).  These are unexpectedly created using the toString() method which is not well formatted.

How do I ensure that request parameters are also formatted using Jackson.  This is key as I need to include a list of filter criteria objects within GET requests.

Currently, I have worked around this by changing the filter criteria object toString() method to return a JSON string and writing a matching argument resolver that can decode that string.

Is this the only way or can it be automated via configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Need to set this configuration class in FeignClient interface.

```
@FeignClient(value = "client", configuration = JacksonFeignConfiguration.class)
public interface YourClient{
   //Your mappings
}
```

Comment: I did this, however the request parameters on the GET requests are not being encoded to JSON only the request/response bodies.